# Search keywords on Excel Mac to return only the matching rows (multiple) in a glossary file

Tags: excel, macos, formula

I have a large excel spreadsheet on Mac with multiple columns (abbreviation, term, definition, synonym, etc. spanning from A2 to ~I16300.) What I need help with is setting up a search function where I type a keyword and only return the rows that contain it. Sort of like an online dictionary but in Excel.
I know this can be done on Windows but the developer ribbon on the MacOS version does not have that option (text box with properties I believe.)

Tried many formulas I had found online and different functions but nothing worked. I could do it in Numbers but I need to have it in Excel. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a helper column and join all the data into one cell. Then check if that one cell contains your search word and return a TRUE.
Then filter the data for TRUE

```
I5  =IFERROR(SEARCH($L$3;TEXTJOIN(" ";TRUE;A5:H5))>0;"")
K5  =FILTER($A$5:$H$13;I5:I13=TRUE;"not found")
```

If you don't want the zeros to show up you could for example use this instead:

```
=IF(FILTER($A$5:$H$13;I5:I13=TRUE;"not found")=0;"";FILTER($A$5:$H$13;I5:I13=TRUE;"not found"))
```

[image]

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you.
One last question, is there a way to clear the results when I delete the keyword from the search L3?

Comment: @iviennes Oh, the result is not cleared by itself? Then you can wrap an if condition around the filter formula. =IF(L3="";"";<your filter formula>)